# wpf mvp listview with gridview long rendering time

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, mvp

I have a user control that has a listview with gridview. 
I am using background worker to start loading animation, get the data and stop loading animation. All is good but the problem is after I get data and bind it to grid, it takes long time to render grid and loading animation freezes in that time.

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress = true };



    public FormUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        presenter = new FormPresenter(this);
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(LoadInfo);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += LoadInfo_RunWorkerCompleted;



        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            EnableLoading(true);

        }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

    }

    void LoadInfo(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        presenter.LoadFormInformation();
    }

    private void LoadInfo_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            //here animation freezes 
            this.AjmStoreLog = this.GridInfo;
            EnableLoading(false);

        }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
    }
```

I need to  call EnableLoading(false); this function when grid rendering complete  not at the LoadInfo_RunWorkerCompleted event.

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1):

There are many cases where performance suffers simply because there's too much work to do, and a lot of that work has to happen on the UI thread. There's no magic bullet solution that can help there - if you have many items in your data source or if your templates are very complex...

I'd suggest looking at UI virtualization first, assuming there are many items and that's the main reason for performance problems. Without UI virtualization, list controls need to render every item in the data source, but enabling it will make it so that only the visible items need to be actually rendered on screen, which makes a massive difference.

Comment: thanks I know there is not one magic way to do it, as far as I read listview is already virtualized, so no luck for me yet. I'll answer here if I could find one

Comment: Then I suggest running under a profiler and gathering more information about what is actually taking the longest; this could give you clues as to what you can optimize. Profilers usually will tell you what's the 'hot path' that hurts performance the most.

Comment: Dear Alex,  I read topics about UI Virtualization in wpf listview with gridview, edited my code accordingly and run  a profiler. I can see that even the listview panel correctly virtualizes (nothing killing virtualization), still it takes huge chunk of time loading data to grid. It can be seen from here  https://imagebin.ca/v/3LPVTQ9sjn1o. it is ok for me to grid panel to load in 4 seconds but what I believe  I need is to fire an event when actual grid rendering is complete to not to end loading animation prematurely

Comment: Now that I am using Background worker and dispatcher to  start loading animation, get the data and end loading animation but this causes that loading animation ends when data is ready and bound to grid. What I believe I need is that I need to end loading animation when actual is rendering of grid is complete. Is there an event to be raised for this, I don't know if its actually possible.

Comment: I don't think there's a difference between rendering and data binding. The way WPF list controls work is when data is bound, the control creates UI containers for each item and adds them to the control's visual tree; this can only happen on the UI thread. From your screenshot it seems each item has a complicated template, even a few milliseconds seems to me like a lot. I don't think there's a way to offload all that to another thread so you'll need to look at simplifying the item templates, or making it so they initialize asynchronously.